# Split list of strings by list of key words

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list of strings 
e.g.{"apple.txt", "orange.sd.2.txt", "apple.2.tf.txt", "orange.txt"} 
and another list of strings to group the first list
e.g. {"apple", "orange"} 
so that the first list is split into a list of lists and looks like this:

{{"apple.txt", "apple.2.tf.txt"},{"orange.txt", "orange.sd.2.txt"}}

How can I achieve this with linq?

Comment: if a string is called "apple.orange.txt" how does it have to behave ?

Comment: Its not a use case but could be in both groups

Comment: Does the order of the final list need to match the order in the grouping list?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var groupedList = firstList.GroupBy(x => secondList.Single(y => x.Name.Contains(y)));
```

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer or an extension of your question?

Comment: You may want to use `First` unless you are positive there can't be more than one key match for a given `firstList` member. You may want to use `FirstOrDefault` unless you are positive every `firstList` member will belong to a group. Otherwise, nicely done.

Comment: You can convert this using a bit more processing with `SelectMany` to handle items belonging to multiple groups: `dataToSplit.SelectMany(ds => keyList.Where(k => ds.Contains(k)).Select(k => new { Key = k, Value = ds }))
           .GroupBy(kds => kds.Key, kds => kds.Value)
`

Comment: @GertArnold I guess a possible answer

Comment: "How about this:" is a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You could group the elements of each of the original `list` by *all* possible keys using `Split`, `SelectMany`, and `GroupBy` with an anonymous type:

```
var list = new List<string> { "apple.txt", "orange.sd.2.txt", "apple.2.tf.txt", "orange.txt" };
var groups = list
    .SelectMany(element => element
        .Split('.')
        .Select(part => new { Part = part, Full = element }))
    .GroupBy(entry => entry.Part);
```

Now you can select the groups you want to keep using `Where`, and convert the results into the nested lists using `Select` and `ToList`:

```
var keys = new List<string> { "apple", "orange" };
var result = group
    .Where(group => keys.Contains(group.Key))
    .Select(group => group
        .Select(entry => entry.Full)
        .ToList())
    .ToList();
```

N.B. Elements of the original list which do not contain any of the specified keys will not appear in the results, and elements which contain more than one of the specified keys will appear more than once in the result.

**Edit:** As @NetMage noted, I've made an incorrect assumption about splitting strings - here's another version, although it's `O(m * n)`:

```
var result = keys
    .Select(key => list.Where(element => element.Contains(key)).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Interesting approach - by converting `keys` to a `HashSet` I think this comes closest to an O(n) solution, though I believe the overhead of processing all the unneeded parts and the assumption that splitting on `.` is viable means it isn't the best answer.

Comment: @NetMage thanks, you're right that's an incorrect assumption - added alternative to my answer

Answer (score 1):

This is one simple way to do it. There is many ways and this will include duplicated key as the comment i made on your question. If many key match the same data the grouping will include the copies.

```
// have the list of keys (groups)
var keyList = new List<string>() {"apple", "orange"};

// have the list of all the data to split
var dataToSplit = new List<string>() 
{
    "apple.txt", 
    "apple.2.tf.txt",
    "orange.txt", 
    "orange.sd.2.txt"
};

// now split to get just as desired you select what you want for each keys
var groupedData = keyList.Select(key => dataToSplit.Where(data => data.Contains(key)).ToList()).ToList();

// groupedData is a List<List<string>>
```

A second option to get the values maybe in a more "object" fashion is to use anonymous. specially good if you will do lots of manipulation and it's more "verbiose" in the code. But if you are new to this i do NOT recommend that approach but anyhow this is it.

```
// have the list of keys (groups)
var keyList = new List<string>() {"apple", "orange"};

// have the list of all the data to split
var dataToSplit = new List<string>() 
{
    "apple.txt", 
    "apple.2.tf.txt",
    "orange.txt", 
    "orange.sd.2.txt"
};

// create the anonymous
var anonymousGroup = keyList.Select(key =>
{
    return new 
    { 
        Key = key, 
        Data = dataToSplit.Where(data => data.Contains(key)).ToList()
    }
});

// anonymousGroup is a List<A> where keeping the order you should access all data for orange like this
var orangeGroup = anonymousGroup.FirstOfDefault(o=> o.Key = "orange"); // get the anonymous
var orangeData = orangeGroup.Data; // get the List<string> for that group
```

A third way with less complexity than O(m*n). The trick is to remove from the collection the data as you go to reduce the chance to recheck over item already processed. This is from my codebase and it's an extension for `List` that simply remove item from a collection based on a predicate and return what has been removed.

```
public static List<T> RemoveAndGet<T>(this List<T> list, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var itemsRemoved = new List<T>();

    // iterate backward for performance
    for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        // keep item pointer
        var item = list[i];

        // if the item match the remove predicate
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            // add the item to the returned list
            itemsRemoved.Add(item);

            // remove the item from the source list
            list.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }

    return itemsRemoved;
}
```

Now with that extension when you have a list you can use it easily like this :

```
// have the list of keys (groups)
var keyList = new List<string>() {"apple", "orange"};

// have the list of all the data to split
var dataToSplit = new List<string>() 
{
    "apple.txt", 
    "apple.2.tf.txt",
    "orange.txt", 
    "orange.sd.2.txt"
};

// now split to get just as desired you select what you want for each keys
var groupedData = keyList.Select(key => dataToSplit.RemoveAndGet(data => data.Contains(key))).ToList();
```

In that case due to the order in both collection the first key is `apple` so it will iterate the 4 items in `dataToSplit` and keep only 2 AND reducing the `dataToSplit` collection to 2 items only being the one with `orange` in them. On the second key it will iterate only over 2 items which will make it faster for this case. Typically this method will be as fast or faster than the first 2 ones i provided while being as clear and still make use of linq.

Comment: I was trying to think of a way to avoid O(m*n) and make this O(n), but I can't see it.

Comment: If you an item with 2 of the key can fall in 2 category you can't do any other way other than O(m*n). If you don't care and these case can fall in a random one it is possible to reduce the complexity. What you need is iterate the data collection and remove from that collection as you find match, this will reduce the subset of data for subsequent keys when building the list.

Comment: Interesting - my iteration was over data then over keys, under the assumption that data is longer, so if you just need the first contained key you can stop early searching keys.

Answer (score 0):

Tuples to the rescue!

```
var R = new List<(string, List<string>)> { ("orange", new List<string>()), ("apple", new List<string>()) };
var L = new List<string> { "apple.txt", "apple.2.tf.txt", "orange.txt", "orange.sd.2.txt" };
R.ForEach(r => L.ForEach(l => { if (l.Contains(r.Item1)) { r.Item2.Add(l); } }));
var resultString = string.Join("," , R.Select(x => "{" + string.Join(",", x.Item2) + "}"));
```

You can build R dynamically trivially if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using this simple code:

```
var list1 = new List<string>() {"apple.txt", "orange.sd.2.txt", "apple.2.tf.txt", "orange.txt"};
var list2 = new List<string>() {"apple", "orange"};
var result = new List<List<string>>();

list2.ForEach(e => {
    result.Add(list1.Where(el => el.Contains(e)).ToList());
});
```